# Получить вектор-столбец матрицы с++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Пусть есть матрица

```
vector< vector<int> > a = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 42}
};
```

Я могу легко получить вектор-строку этой матрицы, например `a[1]` вернет вектор, который содержит `{5, 6, 7, 8}`.

Есть ли способ получить так же просто вектор-столбец матрицы? То есть, например, по индексу `2` получить вектор, который содержит `{3, 7, 11}`.

Comment: Без копирования или введения новых абстракций - нет

Comment: @int3 А как это можно сделать копированием?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<vector<int>> a = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4},
    {5, 6, 7, 8},
    {9, 10, 11, 42}
};

vector<int> b;

for(const auto& e: a) b.push_back(e[2]);
```